# Inability to read spaces from text file in C++

Tags: c++

There is a task about templates in which it is necessary to create a structure - a singly linked list of various types with iteration - integer, real and symbolic. It is necessary to overload >> so that it reads spaces from a text file, while the implementation itself must be uniform, that is, not depend on the type, so I had a problem. How to overload the input operator, regardless of the type, so that it works correctly?

```
friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& file, List<T>& obj)
{
    T elem;

    while (file >> elem)
    {
        obj.AddLast(elem);
    }

    return file;
}
```

Comment: What if `T` is `int`?  What should happen to spaces then?

Comment: `operator>>` is a **formatted** extractor; it begins by skipping leading whitespace, then it extracts into the target object; it stops when it hits trailing whitespace.

Comment: If T is int and there are spaces in the text file, then spaces are completely ignored and numbers are read properly.

Comment: Use `std::getline()` then put it in a `std::istringstream` and set [`std::noskipws`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws) then extract

Comment: If I add {std::noskipws}, then I will have to write any numbers in the text file without spaces at all, otherwise numbers will be read incorrectly, unfortunately.

Comment: The main problem is that my task is to create the uniform operator >> irrespective of type T.

Comment: Not-doable in a general sense. Not everything can be printed.

Comment: Whats the format of the text file? is it a single line of space-separated values - or is it one value per line - or something else? could you maybe post a sample? otherwise this is hard to answer.

Comment: it is a single line of space-separated values.

Comment: You cannot overload the `>>` operator regardless of type.